# Генератор уникальных значений

Tags: python

Необходимо, чтобы цикл `for` выдавал только УНИКАЛЬНЫЕ значения.

Предположим, что USER на input ввёл число 4.
На выходе цикл должен "ситеррировать" только уникальные элементы списка.

Чего тут не хватает???

```
    import random

    a = input("Сколько Вам лет: ")
    b = ("какой-то комментарий 1", "какой-то комментарий 2", 
"какой-то комментарий 3", "какой-то комментарий 4")

    for i in range(int(a)):
        print("С днем рождения, " + random.choice(b))
```

Comment: Можно удалять уже выведенный элемент, тогда при следующем выборе его точно уже не будет

Answer (score 4):

```py
for s in random.sample(b, int(a)):
    print("С днем рождения, " + s)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    import random

    a = input("Сколько Вам лет: ")
    b = ["какой-то комментарий 1", "какой-то комментарий 2", 
"какой-то комментарий 3", "какой-то комментарий 4"]
    random.shuffle(b)
    for i in range(int(a)):
        print("С днем рождения, " + b[i])
```